# is it possible to call sqlite3 instrucations from python?

Tags: python, sqlite, call, instructions

I'd like to call sqlite3 instructions from python script.
By *instructions* i mean:

- .help
- .schema
- .mode
- and rest of instructions listed by ".help" in sqlite3 utility.

I'd be satisfied either by python API or by subprocess.
For example I'd like to execute this script:

```
sqlite3
.mode csv
.import filename tablename
```

In more complicated case, i can always create a bash script and call it from python.
But bash stinks to me. :P

Comment: What functionality do you need that is not available in the default python sqlite3 library? http://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html

Answer (score 0):

No, but you can get the same *data* from your database by using [`PRAGMA` commands](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html) and querying the [system tables](http://www.sqlite.org/fileformat2.html#sqlite_master).

- `.help` is just listing the `sqlite3` tool commands. no point in making those work in Python.
- `.schema` uses `PRAGMA table_info()` and the system tables to show you the schema, formatted as SQL commands.
- Just use the output from the queries to format your data with print statements or the `csv` module to output CSV data.